# mailchimp popup form not showing up

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, popup, mailchimp

I have created a popup form in my mailchimp account and I cannot get it to show up on my site. The code generated is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"xxxx-xxxxx.com","uuid":"xxxxxxxxxxx","lid":"xxxxxxxx"}) })</script>
```

I tried adding it to header.php, footer.php in wordpress but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is probably that the correct jquery version is not being called. I believe you need a minimum of 1.4.4 and you may find if you have a look at the link below it is a problem with how the pop up is looking for the jquery.js file:

https://www.organicweb.com.au/19561/wordpress/mailchimp-popup-instructions/

Answer (score 11):

It might be that you yourself are already subscribed. Here's JS that can delete the cookie that marks that:

```
document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
document.cookie = "MCPopupSubscribed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe mailchimp uses cookies to display the popup only once, so once you see it once on your site, it won't display again unless you delete your cookies.  Not sure if there is a setting to change this or not.

Comment: Not the case. It does not show up at all. Once you get it working, just then you answer kicks in.

Comment: This is late, but I've cleared everything, my site and browser cache, still not seeing it. I'm not sure how to test this.

Comment: You could also use incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

it could be conflict with existing jquery.

the embed.js will auto search for jquery.js at the web root directory.
just place the file there and it should works.

if you do not want to mess up your web root by creating another duplicate jquery js file, you can use htaccess to map it to your existing path.

`RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^/?jquery.js$  /themes/inspinia/vendors/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js [L]`

or, visit this page for more detail:
https://www.organicweb.com.au/19561/wordpress/mailchimp-popup-instructions/